# Problema con algoritmo del banquero

Tags: algoritmos

tengo el siguiente ejercicio del algoritmo del banquero, pero no encuentro una forma de solucionarlo, espero me puedan ayudar:

**Una computadora tiene 6 unidades de un recurso no compartible, con n procesos competidores. Cada proceso puede necesitar hasta 2 unidades del recurso. ¿Para qué valores de n está el sistema libre de interbloqueos?
**

Gracias.

He intentado resolverlo manualmente, y según yo la respuesta sería n>=3, pero no me convence.

Comment: Y por qué dices que esa sería la respuesta? Y por qué no te convence? Tiene sentido que el sistema esté libre de interbloqueos con n >= 3????

Comment: Porque lo resolví de manera similar como a la persona que me contestó en forma de respuesta. Pero expresé mal mi resultado, es n<=3. Siento eso.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion es **facil** una inecuacion, la podemos de la sguiente manera
6-2n>= 0
n <= 3

donde n es el valor que buscas, dime si te sirve.